# Sleeping less than a second in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, delay, sleep, wait, thread-sleep

The `Unix.sleep` function can suspend the program for whole seconds, but how can you suspend it for less than a second?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The classical Unix solution for this is to use select() with no file descriptors:

```
let minisleep (sec: float) =
    ignore (Unix.select [] [] [] sec)
```

Comment: and don't forget about signals that may interrupt select

Answer (score 15):

from [Unix](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html) module

```
val sleepf : float -> unit
```

> Stop execution for the given number of seconds. Like sleep, but
>   fractions of seconds are supported.

Comment: Note that this function was added in 4.03.0.  Prior versions of OCaml don't have access to this particular function.

Answer (score 14):

The `Thread.delay` function pauses the thread for the given number of seconds, but it takes a float, allowing you to pause the thread for less than a second.